# AudioInputStream: Pop noise with Java 1.7 and 1.8 on macOS and 8-bit wav files

Tags: java, macos, audio, java-8

I have a weird problem with playing samples using AudioInputStream. 
Three scenarios:

- macOS, java 1.6: works perfectly
- win, java 1.8: works perfectly
- macOS, java 1.8: heavy pop sounds

The code I created for testing is straight forward. The sample is clean (zero cross at start and end). The first pop occurs already on soundLine.start() which is completely independent on the sample. The last pop occurs on soundLine.close() where the sample has been finished since couple of seconds. I added some delay to the code so it is easy to recognize on which place the code is.

I created demo videos where you can hear what happens:

- on macOS Sierra (tested on a MBP and an iMac. First run with Java-8, second with Java-6. You can see the used java version on the screen):
  https://youtu.be/bROPZq_33ME
- on win (win7 running in Parallels): https://youtu.be/PGd4iW3oO4Y

As you can see (hear) the only problem is Java 1.8 under macOS. I also tested java 1.7 with the same result. Only on 1.6 the playback is correct.
The pop sound sounds strange because the sound has been recorded with the internal micro of my MBP. It is a typical pop sound you can hear when switching power on/off of a bad designed amplifier.

**ADDENDUM: the problem seems to occur with 8-bit wav files only. 16 bit works fine.**

**ADDENDUM: in the mean time listed as bug: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8172164**

Can anyone reproduce the problem? Any idea what's the reason? I currently assume a bug in Java.

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

public class Soundtest
{
    protected File sample=new File("user1.wav");

    public Soundtest()
    {                   
        SourceDataLine soundLine = null;
        int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024; 

        System.out.println("AudioInputStream test with "+System.getProperty("java.version")+" on "+System.getProperty("os.name"));
        // Set up an audio input stream piped from the sound file.
        try 
        {       

            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sample);
            AudioFormat audioFormat = audioInputStream.getFormat();
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);

            //Soundline ist noch nicht angelegt -> angelegen.
            if(soundLine==null)
            {
                soundLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
                soundLine.open(audioFormat);
                soundLine.start();
            }
            System.out.println("Started");
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            System.out.println("Playing");
            int nBytesRead = 0;
            byte[] sampledData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while (nBytesRead != -1) 
            {
                nBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(sampledData, 0, sampledData.length);
                if (nBytesRead >= 0) 
                {                           
                    soundLine.write(sampledData, 0, nBytesRead);                        
                }                               
            }           
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("Draining");
            soundLine.drain();

            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("Closing");
            soundLine.close();
        }           
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {          
        new Soundtest();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fine on my Mac.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out that it only happens with 8 bit wav files. Could you confirm?

Comment: Yes, it does seem to be 8 bit only

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code that I can tell. I've ran it myself with Java 1.8.0_60 on macOS Sierra 10.12.2, and there were no popping sounds through my headset, nor was there popping when coming out of the Internal Speakers. The only reason I could think of right now is that for some reason Java 1.8 doesn't like the audio interface or medium you're using, if it's any different than the generic speakers on your Mac. It could even be possible that audio buffering was done differently in 1.8. Try raising the buffer size to prevent under-runs (which could be the cause of the popping).

Comment: Thanks! I don't think it's hardware. Same on the MBP, an old MBA and my iMac. The buffer size has no influence. already tested it. Beside this, the pop occurs before the stream is feed with data. I can reduce the code and cut it just after soundLine.start() to provoke the first pop.

Comment: you gave me an idea! It happens with 8-bit wav files only!

Comment: @Dark.Rider awesome glad you could figure it out!

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help... I need working 8-bit wavs.

Comment: @Dark.Rider why must they be 8-bit?

Comment: it's an embedded project which target uses 8 bit samples